# How to add different vue-gtm (Google tag manager) IDs to specific routes in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, google-tag-manager

Let's say we've got these route paths:

1. `/route1`
2. `/route2`
3. `/route3`

Then we have Google Tag manager IDs:

1. GTM-12345
2. GTM-54321

Per Google's docs, they need 2 code blocks added in `head` and `body`.

So let's say we use `vue-gtm` for Vue V2, like this:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createGtm } from "vue-gtm";
import router from "./router";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);

app.use(
  createGtm({
    id: "GTM-12345",
    enabled: true,
    vueRouter: router,
  })
);
```

---

What would be a clean way of adding 2 of these plugins with a different ID, so that the 2 code blocks with ID `GTM-12345` are added (by `vue-gtm`) to `/route1`, and other 2 code blocks are added to `/route2` and `/route3`.

To rephrase, routes 2 and 3 need to be tracked under ID 2, and route 1 needs to be tracked under ID 1.

Tried:

1. Adding 2 `app.use()` -- only 1 gets added
2. Adding code on mount -- 2 scripts are added

Comment: You could add both and make a filter on each dashboard. Otherwise I cannot see how you can add a script and remove it depending of the path.

Comment: The `vue-gtm` package supports blacklisted routes, but I can't add 2 instances of it. The scripts could be added twice, but they don't support blacklisted routes or at least it's not clear how to add them. Also, if the scripts are added they'll be unaware of Vue's internal routes, probably.